# GCHandle.FromIntPtr always says "value belongs to another domain" even with minimalistic test

Tags: c#, .net, mono, garbage-collection

I'm using mono 2.0.5 and the following example always results in "ArgumentException: GCHandle value belongs to a different domain".

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Weak);
IntPtr ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);
GCHandle testHandle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr);
```

What in the world is going on here? Is this a bug with mono?

Comment: If, it was mono specific bug, I would guess you could try reproducing it on Windows platform. If it shows on Windows too.. would be tempting to not call it a bug in Mono?

Comment: Can you replace `this` with `new object()` so that the test is stand-alone?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your mono installation, this works correctly on a recent mono. 2.0.5 is ancient.